# makefile error: No rule to make target How to fix?

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors

The error:

**make: *** No rule to make target 'build-x86_64'.  Stop.**

My makefile:

```
x86_64_asm_source_files := $(shell find src/impl/x86_64 -name *.asm)
x86_64_asm_object_files := $(patsubst src/impl/x86_64/%.asm, build/x86_64/%.o, $(x86_64_asm_source_files))

$(x86_64_asm_object_files): build/x86_64/%.o : src/impl/x86_64/%.asm
    mkdir -p $(dir $@) && \
    nasm -f elf64 $(patsubst build/x86_64/%.o, src/impl/x86_64/%.asm, $@) -o $@

.PHONY: build-x86_64
build-x86_64: $(x86_64_asm_object_files)
    mkdir -p dist/x86_64 && .
    x86_64-elf-ld -n -o dist/x86_64/kernel.bin -T targets/x86_64/linker.ld $(x86_64_asm_object_files) && \
    cp dist/x86_64/kernel.bin targets/x86_64/iso/boot/kernel.bin && \
    grub-mkrescue /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc -o dist/x86_64/target.iso targets/x86_64/iso
```

Comment: What is the filename of this makefile?  What command line did you use to invoke make?  It looks to me like `make` is not using this makefile.

Comment: 1. "Makefile" (This is the only makefile in my project.). 2. I use Docker.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I use Docker" (I know what Docker is, it's just that doesn't help me solve your issue).  The `make` command can't find this makefile (I suspect).  make will look in the working directory where it's running to find the makefile.  If make can't find the makefile, then the directory you're running it in is not the directory containing the makefile... or the name of the makefile is something else but you say it's `Makefile` which is fine so it must be the wrong directory.

Comment: Oh! This is what I meant:


`PS C:\Hope OS> docker run --rm -it -v /root/env hopeos-buildenv









root@7c0ee0e138ac:~/env# make build-x86_64`


/root/env is where my makefile and the rest of my src code is

Comment: Based on the info provided there's no explanation for the error you see, so there must be something else going on here that we can't see.  You can try running `make -p` so make prints its database and look at the output to see if the `build-x86_64` target is there.  You can run `make -d` to see everything make is doing (it'll print a lot of stuff so probably redirect it to a file and then use `less` or something to review it) including which makefiles it's finding.

Comment: i did `make -d` and it returned this: **make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.**

Comment: It must have printed out something else besides that... the`-d` option prints a TON of debug output.  But if that's the error you get at the end then it's even more proof that your makefile is not in the same directory where you're running make.  Why don't you change your command to add in an `ls` operation, and maybe a `pwd` operation, before you run `make`, to see where you are and what's there?

Comment: I did `ls` and it didn't return anything...
I did `pwd` and it returned `/root/env`

Comment: OK, well, there's nothing in the directory, and nothing means your makefile is not there.  You're in the wrong directory or you're not mounting the data from your system into the docker image properly or something.  In any event, this doesn't have anything to do with make.  You'll need to figure out your docker situation, so that you can see your files, before you can run make.

Comment: I think I have a solution, it involves deleting everything, but I'm following a tutorial, so I can just copy it from there again. I think the thing that caused the error was an incorrect path (`WORKDIR /root/div`).